# Octave Replace elements in a vector under certain circumstances

Tags: matlab, octave

I have two vectors as below:

```
p = zeros(5,1);
hx = [0.1; 0.3; 0.7; 0.9; 0.2];
```

the task is to replace elements in `p` from `0` to `1` if elements in `hx` `>=0.5`. Expeted output:

```
p =

   0
   0
   1
   1
   0
```

It can be achieved by below code, what I don't understand is: as `pos = find(hx >= 0.5);` gives a 2D vector, how to understand `p(pos,1)=1;`? How could this final line of code knows which index of `p` corresponding to the right element in `pos`? There seems no obvious connection between those two.
On the other hand, how could this be done through for loop and if statement?

```
pos = find(hx >= 0.5);  
p(pos,1)=1;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` returns the a list of (linear) indices where the condition in the parentheses is true. In your case, this would be `[3;4]`, since the condition is satisfied in element 3 and 4.

The second line sets the elements with rows indicated by `pos` and column 1 to 1.

You could do a loop

```
for idx = 1:length(hx);
    if hx(idx) >=0.5
       p(idx,1) = 1;
    end
end
```

but this would be very un-Matlab/Octave. Much nicer would be

```
p(hx>=0.5) = 1;
```

which avoids the detour via `find`

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in a single line of code. But make sure p and hx have equal number of elements.

```
p(hx>=0.5)=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I could find without loops is this:

```
p = hx >= 0.5
```

It will output a vector of the same size as hx but with ones where the condition was met.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved using following code snippet:

```
VectorWithZeros = VectorWithZeros + ReplaceWithScalar * (VectorWithZeros == 0)
```